# threejs: how to render a texture with custom shaders INCLUDING the textures UV offsets

Tags: three.js, shader, uv-mapping

I want to render a texture to a plane using custom shaders. This texture has an 'offset' property set, that works correctly when I use a standard threejs material. However, I cannot figure out how to access these offsets in my custom fragment shader. It simply renders the whole texture over the whole plane:

shaders:

```
<script id="vertex_shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main() {
        vUv = uv;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix *
            modelViewMatrix *
            vec4(position,1.0);
    }

    </script>

    <script id="fragment_shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

    uniform sampler2D texture1;
    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main()
    {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture1, vUv); 
    }

    </script>
```

if I could somehow say something like:

```
gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture1, vUv + texture1.offset);
```

? Maybe that would work. But obviously that throws an error.

UPDATE:
so I sent the texture offset in as a uniform and that works. Dont know why I didn't think of that.

Comment: Yes. I wrote "threejs" in the title of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then the answer should be to add and use the `uniform mat3 uvTransform;` uniform to your fragment shader.

THREE will look for and populate that uniform with the texture transformation (which includes `texture1.offset`), when rendering the texture onto your geometry.

You should be able to access and extract the data supplied to `texture1.offset` to offset your texture sampling as follows:

```
<script id="vertex_shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {
    vUv = uv;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
}

</script>

<script id="fragment_shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

    // [UPDATE] The uv offset uniform we defined below
    uniform vec2 uvOffset;
    // [UPDATE] The texture uniform we defined below
    uniform sampler2D texture;

    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main()
    {
        // [UPDATE] Apply offset to texture lookup
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, vUv + uvOffset); 
    }

</script>
```

You would then accompany the vertex and fragment shaders above, with the following `THREE.ShaderMaterial`:

```
<script>
  var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: THREE.UniformsUtils.merge([
    {
      //Declare texture uniform in shader
      texture: { type: 't', value: null }, 
      //Declare texture offset in shader
      uvOffset : { type : 'v', value : new THREE.Vector2(0,0) } 
    }
  ]),
  vertexShader: 
  document.getElementById('vertexshader').textContent,
  fragmentShader: 
  document.getElementById('fragmentshader').textContent
});

// Shader uniforms can be updated like so
material.uniforms.map.value = yourTexture;
material.uniforms.uvOffset.value = yourTextureOffsetVector2;
</script>
```

Comment: That looks great! it doesnt work for me though, it has no effect. I cant find any documentation on this "uvTransform" that automatically gets passed to the shaders. Is there a standard way to apply the matrix to the texture?

Comment: How are you loading the shader? via THREE.Shader, or THREE.RawShader ?

Comment: var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial. If there is a better, more standard way to acheive a simple UV mapped custom shader, id love to find an example somewhere

Comment: You might have to apply the actual offset to the uniform something like `myMaterial.uniforms.uvOffset.value = myTexture.transformMatrix` or whatever it's called

This would be a mat3 so you have to multiply it, for the offset alone you could probably do a `uniform vec2 uOffset` `myMateria.uniforms.uOffset.value = myTexture.offset`

Comment: @korrbit have just updated answer - hope this helps!